# How to pass callback from one child component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main component, `App`, which has two child components, `Player`, and `VideoList`, where `Player` is a wrapper around [`react-player`](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player), heavily based off of the `react-player` demo.

`Player` has a method `renderLoadButton()` which creates a button that loads a particular video when clicked. I would like to have several of these buttons inside of my `VideoList` component.

I am attempting to pass the `renderLoadButton()` function up into the parent component, and then down into the `VideoList` component where I can call it.

Here is the code for `render()` function of the parent component. Both my `<Player/>` and `<VideoList/>` components instantiated here.

I get the following error on the line mentioned in the comment.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderLoadButton' of undefined

```
render() {
    const dragHandlers = {onStart: this.onStart, onStop: this.onStop};
    const {deltaPosition, controlledPosition} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div className="fullscreen">

              <Draggable handle="strong" bounds={'body'}{...dragHandlers}>
                  <div style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: '30%', right: '50%'}} className="video-box no-cursor">
                      <Player ref={instance=>{this.player = instance}} title="VIDEO" url='https://streamable.com/nfec3'/>
                  </div>
              </Draggable>
              <Draggable handle="strong" bounds={'body'}{...dragHandlers}>

               <div>
                   {/*Error on the following line*/}
                   <VideoList callback = {(x,y)=> this.player.renderLoadButton(x,y)}/>
               </div>
              </Draggable>
          </div>

          <div className="App-footer">
              <img src={vinyl} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <h1>Radio</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: `this.player.renderLoadButton` - how `this.player` is defined? Shouldn't it be `this.renderLoadButton` (with no `player`)?

Comment: @Alex `this.player` is defined on the line that starts with `<Player`, `player` is an instance of the `Player` component which has the `renderLoadButton` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code you provided you are doing it right i have created similar working model as yours it is working fine:
  https://codesandbox.io/s/6y5p9woqq3

You can add your code to sandbox so that we will able to figure out what is the problem.

**Edit**

The Problem with your code is not `index.js` but is in `VideoList.js` as per your minimal code
`VideoList.js`:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

class VideoList extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("dd");
    return this.props.callback('www.something.com','BUTTON');
  }
}
export default VideoList;
```

Here you are trying to return a prop which contains a function not the original jsx for better clarity try console logging like this
  `console.log("dd",this.props.callback)` 
which shows a object  returning your `this.player.renderLoadButton` function. so when you are trying to return it which returns just a function which cannot be rendered it is causing errors.

So if you have to pass that function which returns jsx don't use ref.Create a new obj or instance of Player class and extract the function from it and then pass it as prop to the videoList and the call it in render return.

so your `App` component should look like:

```
    class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const obj = new Player 
    const func = obj.renderLoadButton   
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <Player title="VIDEO" url='https://streamable.com/nfec3'/>
        <VideoList func={func} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

then your `VideoList` looks like:

```
    class VideoList extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("dd");
    return (
   <div>
     { this.props.func('www.something.com','BUTTON') }
    </div>
    )
  }
}
export default VideoList;
```

here is working code :https://codesandbox.io/s/jpqnxwyyy

**Edit 2:**

i don't think it is possible that way. one thing you can do is use the same jsx every where and use the another function as props every where to call again. like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/7zwyl0yp3j

Comment: Interesting, this seems exactly like what i am trying to do. I can't spot the difference between this and my code.

Comment: that is why i am asking you to add your code to sandbox so that i can see what is the problem

Comment: Thank you, i added a simplified version of my code to the sandbox until it broke in the same way described in my original post.You can see it here https://codesandbox.io/s/lyp867yl3z

Comment: @user3504732 see the edit i have added my new answer to the previous answer

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful, but in my real code, the `renderLoadButton` function has to set the state of `Player`, so i need to access the actual `Player` instance that is rendered, not another one. See my problem here https://codesandbox.io/s/4yo131p57

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. i wish that could work somehow, but i will use your solution. you've been very helpful.